# How to set title and width in a grid table for both PDF and HTML in restructured text?

Tags: pdf, format, python-sphinx, title, restructuredtext

I would like to have the title with the automatical number and set the table width by myself.
What's more, the grid table is long, I don't know how to show the table in two pages in PDF.

I use the grid table because some of the columns needs to be integrated.

I tried to use

```
.. tabularcolumns:: |m{3cm}|m{11cm}|
```

but I did not find the place to set the title.

I tried to use

```
.. table:: Specifications
```

The title "Specifications" did not show.

I tried to use

```
:class: longtable
```

but it did not take effect. The whole table shows in a page, but the former page of the table is nearly empty, which looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I forgot the indent which led to the missing title and the misfunction of longtable.

About the widths, I found the attribute "grid" is helpful which can overspread the PDF page.

```
.. table:: Personnel
   :widths: grid

   +----------+---------+
   |Name      |Age      |
   +==========+=========+
   |Bill      |39       |
   +----------+---------+
   |Jane      |38       |
   +----------+---------+
```

If the table is too long, the following attribute also works.

```
  :class: longtable
```